# Call php with ajax

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

I am using VM 3.0.2 with JM 3.3.
I know that order cancellation is, unfortunately, not available in VM3 and I am trying to add it.
To do this, I added a link to the "order list" on the front end for registered users. I have also changed it so that if the order is still in "Confirmed By Customer", it adds a button called cancel.

I added an ajax call when "cancel" is clicked to call a file.php with the following:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['id'])) { 
            $id= $_REQUEST['id'];
            if ($id) {

                    if (!class_exists('VirtueMartModelOrders'))
                            require( JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'models' . DS . 'orders.php' );
                    $modelOrder = new VirtueMartModelOrders();
                    $order['order_status'] = 'X';
                    $order['virtuemart_order_id'] = $id;
                    $order['customer_notified'] = 1;
                    $modelOrder->updateStatusForOneOrder($id, $order, true);
            }
    }
```

My ajax call is:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".can").click(function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: '/orders/f.php',
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert('tritri');
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Problem is that the result is always alerting the word `tritri` and order is not getting cancelled... I have placed `f.php` in `views/orders/tmpl`...

What am I doing wrong? Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

A jquery ajax request is still technically "successful" as long as the *ajax* request doesn't run into an actual error in the process of execution-- as long as it's successful in hitting the endpoint and returning with something, it's successful-- it doesn't know about your application state.

So what you need to do is gain some insight into what's actually happening on the other end. You can use the new Joomla [`JResponseJson`](https://docs.joomla.org/JSON_Responses_with_JResponseJson) class to help return an object that will have an application-specific (rather than ajax-specific) success / failure message.

Psuedo-code:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['id'])) { 
        $id= $_REQUEST['id'];
        if ($id) {
                if (!class_exists('VirtueMartModelOrders')) require( JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'models' . DS . 'orders.php' );
                $modelOrder = new VirtueMartModelOrders();
                $order['order_status'] = 'X';
                $order['virtuemart_order_id'] = $id;
                $order['customer_notified'] = 1;
                try 
                {
                    $result = $modelOrder->updateStatusForOneOrder($id, $order, true);
                    echo new JResponseJson($result);
                }
                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    // assuming the model throws a real exception-- otherwise check the $result value for success / failure
                    echo new JResponseJson($e);
                }
        }
}
```

Then, in your ajax function's `success` block, check what result is there, and if it's an error message alert / display it, or continue processing if it's a success message:

```
  success: function(data) {
    if(data.success){
      // real success
    } else {
      // handle error
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
    alert(err);
  }
```

Hope this helps!